# Nested Batch Files with Task Scheduler return codes

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

I have some batch files that run some tasks certain days of the week and I thought they were working fine until my colleague, who needs the tasks, pointed out that my code was sending an email saying that the process had failed, but Task Scheduler is indicating that tasks are running fine. We then checked the outputs and they appear to be correct.

Essentially my batch file calls another batch file, that one runs an executable and sometimes a python program (depending on which task it is). The return code of that batch file is then checked and the appropriate email is sent (I have attached the code of one my these batch files below).

My question is: If the executable fails, and hence the internal batch file fails and the failed email python script is run, does the overall batch file return as 0x00? or would it return the error code of the internal batch file as "something" went wrong?

```
ECHO ON
cd G:\Reports\Batch Files\
G:
call ContactsReview.bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    python G:\mtsprograms\python\ContactsFailed.py
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    python G:\mtsprograms\python\ContactsReviewEmail.py
)
```

My reasoning for this question is that if ContactsReview.bat failed and the error check runs the ContactsFailed.py script, does the overall batch file think "Hey, I finished my script, return 0x00"? I wrote this code assuming it would think "ContactsReview.bat failed with *this* error, handle the error, and return *errorcode*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it - you detect an error via ERRORLEVEL, but then you run another command (python). So now your ERRORLEVEL reports the return status of your python command, not your ContactsReview.bat call.

You must save the ERRORLEVEL in a variable if you want to preserve it, and then you can use EXIT /B to exit your master script with the appropriate return code.

One thing to be aware of - ERRORLEVEL is set to a new return code every time an external command like python.exe is called. But cmd.exe is not consistent with how it handles internal commands. Generally, all internal commands will set ERRORLEVEL if an error occurs (DEL being one exception), but some commands like ECHO and GOTO do not clear the ERRORLEVEL upon success, and other commands like DIR and CD do clear the ERRORLEVEL upon success.

Anyway, the following should solve your problem.

```
echo on
cd /d G:\Reports\Batch Files\
call ContactsReview.bat
set "err=%errorlevel%"
if %err% neq 0 (
    python G:\mtsprograms\python\ContactsFailed.py
) else (
    python G:\mtsprograms\python\ContactsReviewEmail.py
)
exit /b %err%
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo exit 1`.

You test errorlevel and exit with whatever code you want. See the `/b` parameter

Comment: The OP is asking how to preserve the ERRORLEVEL and return that value, not how to detect an error.

Answer (score 0):

Read [%errorlevel%](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html):

> Almost all applications and utilities will set an exit code when they
>   complete/terminate.

- Note that *almost all* does not mean *all*; conversely, a lot of commands keep `%errorlevel%` unchanged.
- However, a non-zero errorlevel in CLI as well as in a batch script is  always raised by (at least) syntax error.

So your `ContactsReview.bat` could be as follows ([note `exit /B %AppErrorlevel%`](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)); :

```
:: some stuff
:: clear errorlevel before calling your app:
(call ) 
:: execute your app (executable) here
:: remember errorlevel raised by your app:
set /A "AppErrorlevel=errorlevel"
:: other stuff which could raise non-zero error level although your app succeeds
:: force your batch to return right errorlevel code: 
exit /B %AppErrorlevel%
```

Learn more how to force `%errorlevel%` to `0` by `(call )` command in dbenham's answer to another question at SuperUser: [setting ERRORLEVEL to 0](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602):

> If you want to force the errorlevel to `0`, then you can use this
>   totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. *The space
>   after call is critical*. If you want to set the errorlevel to `1`, you
>   can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after call.
>
> ```
> (call)
> echo %errorlevel%
> (call )
> echo %errorlevel%
> ```